# Can't apply the SparkR::sampleBy function to a sparklyr dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, sparkr, sparklyr

I've read a parquet file using the `df_pqt_tbl <- spark_read_parquet(...)` function.
My environment is Databricks.
I'd like to use the `SparkR::sampleBy` function to do a stratified sampling, but I'm getting an error:

```
class(df_pqt_tbl)

df_train <- SparkR::sampleBy(df_pqt_tbl, col = 'labels',
                     fractions = list('0'=0.7, '1'=0.7),
                     seed = 12345)
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘sampleBy’ for signature ‘"tbl_spark",
>   "character", "list", "numeric"’

Is there a way to transform a *tbl_spark* in a *spark dataframe* so that I can use the *sampleBy* function on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is!  SparkSQL tables are the common interface between `SparkR` and `sparklyr`.  The error is telling you that you have a type mismatch, but if you work with SparkSQL tables you can find common ground.

In your case, use the `sql()` function from `SparkR` and select all from your `sparklyr` table.

```
## Read parquet using sparklyr
df_pqt_tbl <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "path", name = "sparklyr_tbl")

## Use SparkSQL to access in SparkR
pqt_tblDF <- sparkR::sql("select * from sparklyr_tbl")

## Now use functions from SparkR
df_train <- sparkR::sampleBy(df_pqt_tbl, col = 'labels',
                     fractions = list('0'=0.7, '1'=0.7),
                     seed = 12345)
```

To go the other way you would have create a temporary view from `SparkR` and then read the view into a `sparklyr` object.

`sparkR::createOrReplaceTempView(sparkRDF, "sparkSQL_table")`

then use

```
sparklyr_tbl <-  sparklyr::spark_read_table(sc, "sparkSQL_table")
```

Then you can apply functions from `sparklyr` to your `sparklyr_tbl` object.